# jupyter notebook markdown code cell background color

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

If I write code block in a text cell with code quote as below

````
```java
//some code here
```
````

Can I change the code block background color to light grey for all such code cells?

## Update[10/12/19]

per @vi_rises's comments, if using jupyter, then config file path is:

```
.jupyter/custom/custom.css
```

Add below content will change text line background color:

```
.rendered_html code.language-java {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

markdown cell text:
java code section start

````
```java
/* HelloWorld.java
 */

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

java code section end
````

The output looks like below:
[image]

I wish to whole java code rectangle area if it's possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below css property to the custom.css file present under ~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css

```
code.language-java {
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

You can change color as per your need.

[image: before executing]

[image: after executing]

Comment: for jupyter, the config file changed to .jupyter/custom/custom.css, but after add above code, sounds like doesn't work for me. not sure if any difference between jupyter and ipython!

Comment: @lucky1928 for jupyter try `.rendered_html  code.language-java {background-color: #e5e5e5}` instead of above answer.

Comment: Great, it works now, I prefer to change the whole code block background color. now it only change background of valid text line. Is it possile?

Comment: @lucky1928 what do you mean by valid text line?